# datetime.strptime is giving me the wrong month

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

I have to use `datetime` to change the a date from `str` to `date` but I'm getting an unexpected result:

```
strd = "2020-02-06"
dated = datetime.strptime(strd, '%Y-%M-%d').date()
print(dated)
```

I expect the result should be `2020-02-06` but the output is `2020-01-06`.

What is causing this?

Comment: dated = datetime.strptime(strd, '%Y-%m-%d').date() you are using the incorrect date format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`%M` is for minutes](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), not months. Since you aren't providing a value for months you're getting the default.

Use `%m` instead:

```py
dated = datetime.strptime(strd, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
#                                    ^
```